# Indentation Error for a loop

Tags: python

I keep getting a IndentationError: expected an indented block. Why is this error occurring?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r'D:\Programming\Lab1\lab1.gdb'
env.overwriteOutput = 1
env.qualifiedFieldNames = "UNQUALIFIED"

#list the feature classes
soils = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for soils in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
```

Comment: You have nothing in your loop... What are you trying to do? I would also recommend `for soil in soils:` because you already have the list as a `soils` variable

Comment: You're also saying `soils = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` then referring to `arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()` again in your loop definition. If you want to loop through each "feature class" then your loop should be something like `for feature_class in soils:`

Answer (score 4):

Python is expecting an indented block, which wasn't there:

```
for soils in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    # here should be something
```

By providing some values we solve the problem, for example by putting `pass` value, which does nothing, but solves `IndentationError` issue.

```
for soils in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    pass
```

There is another trick:

```
for soils in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(): pass
```

which also solves that issue.

Comment: Code without explanation does not help. Please add some explanation to the answer

Comment: That's true, Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing code inside your for loop.

Try:

```
for soil in soils:
    print(soil)
    # or pass
```